# @initbinder not working for specific model attribute

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, annotations

I am using @valid and @initbinder for validation of the data being passed to the service but I am facing an issue that `@InitBinder` is working only globally,i.e.

```
@InitBinder // possible to leave off for global behavior
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
    binder.setValidator(new LoginRequestValidator());
}
```

and not for a particular model attribute like I have an model object named LoginRequest :

```
@InitBinder("LoginRequest") // possible to leave off for global behavior
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
    binder.setValidator(new LoginRequestValidator());
}
```

In this case the validator is not being called at all.. is this the right way to do this? or am I missing something?

Comment: How does the signature of your controller method look like?

Comment: `public @ResponseBody LoginResponse performLogin(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looking at the signature of your method it has to be

```
@InitBinder("loginRequest")
```

with a **small l**

The value of `@InitBinder` can be one of the following

- The name of a model attribute
- The name of a request parameter
- If none of the above apply, then the name of the class can be used, but starting with a **small letter**. That's how Spring exposes unnamed attributes to the model.

Comment: just wanted to know one more thing that can we have a common initbinder for more that 1 validators ?

Comment: You can have one validator per model (or class), if you mean that. So a common init binder method could set the validator depending on the model / class. Be aware that the modern approach to validation is JSR 303 Bean Validation, which btw eliminates the need for manually setting a validator.

Comment: I have a base controller which is extended by all other controllers, so I was thinking of putting a common @InitBinder there which will call all the validators defined by me.. so wanted to know if that possible ?

Comment: and yeah I cannot use the JSR 303 bean validation as the input to the service is the form of JSON. I am sending the data directly from the js to service. correct me, if I am wrong..

Comment: Does that mean that you call more than one validator per object, e.g. two validators for `loginRequest`? That's not directly possible. If, on the other hand, you have, say, one validator for `loginRequest`, one for `SomethingElse` you could call `binder.getObjectName()` or `binder.getTarget()` and if it's a `loginRequest` set the `LoginRequestValidator` etc.

Comment: And yeah, you can use Bean Validation. It does not matter how you send your data :)

Comment: I have validators for other model objects other than LoginRequest too.. so I am planning to put them in a common place so validation could be done as per the request coming in to the service

Comment: Ok. So you have three choices:
- The approach I just suggested
- Bean Validation
- Even if you have one base Controller, you can still use your initial approach: One Binder method for each model.

Comment: thanks @zeroflagL.. will try the solution you proposed.. will try that `binder.getTarget()` option then will get the target and will invoke the respective validator as per the value returned by this method..

Comment: is it possible to set the initbinder to a method name?

Comment: Can I apply init binder to a particular method and model object related to that controller only? how can I do that?

Answer (score 10):

@a-better-oliver's answer is great, but below is an another approach to the same problem with Spring, more verbose but typesafe:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
  if (binder.getTarget() != null 
      && LoginRequest.class.equals(binder.getTarget().getClass())) {
    binder.setValidator(new LoginRequestValidator());
  }
}
```

This way we do not rely on the hard-coded string and also do not care how Spring exposes unnamed attributes.