# @InitBinder in spring boot not working with @RequestBody

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

If I use @InitBinder without limiting it,it is working fine with @RequestBody to validate my objects.

```
@InitBinder
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(validator);
}



@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public CustomerQuickRegisterEntity saveNewCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody  CustomerQuickRegisterEntity customerEntity,BindingResult result)
{
    if(result.hasErrors())
    {
        return new CustomerQuickRegisterEntity();
    }
    return customerQuickRegisterRepository.save(customerEntity);

}
```

But problem is that when i limit it to just one object by doing it as `@InitBinder("customerEntity")` it is not validating the object. So I have searched through stackoverflow and found that `@InitBinding` only works with objects annotated with `@ModelAttribute`. Then my question is that it is working fine with `@RequestBody` when I use it as `@InitBinder` but does not work well when I use it as `@InitBinder("customerEntity")` ...why is it so?
Is there any other way to validate Objects(Not properties of object Individually) associated with `@RequestBody`

Comment: It simply cannot work with `@RequestBody` as the binding framework (`@ModelAttribute`) is totally different then the message convert framework used for `@RequestBody`. The binder isn't used when using `@RequestBody`. The method with arguments is always called, the one with an argument is only called for a model object named `customerEntity` it will not be invoked.

Comment: But it working fine with `@RequestBody` when I use it as `@InitBinding` without limiting it to any particular object. This is confusing

Comment: @DineshShende have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341543/initbinder-not-working-for-specific-model-attribute)

Comment: You hit a corner case as the `WebDataBinder` is actually used for validation. However when you are limiting it with a name it is the name of a modelAttribute NOT the name of some other arbitrary object. A `@RequestBody` annotated argument isn't part of the model.

Comment: @ankur-singhal Thanks man...The solution with first small letter for class not is working ..thanks for suggetion

Comment: @DineshShende ok posted teh answer for your acceptance/upvote.

Comment: m-deinum You are correct that @RequestBody annotation arguments are not part of model but as per solution gien here my problem is solved [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341543/initbinder-not-working-for-specific-model-attribute) ..But i guess it may not be technicallly correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs,

> Default is to apply to all command/form attributes and all request
>   parameters processed by the annotated handler class. Specifying model
>   attribute names or request parameter names here restricts the
>   init-binder method to those specific attributes/parameters, with
>   different init-binder methods typically applying to different groups
>   of attributes or parameters.

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341543/initbinder-not-working-for-specific-model-attribute)

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but I've managed to get the `@InitBinder` annotation to bind my custom `Validator` to a `@Valid @RequestBody` parameter like this:

```
@InitBinder
private void bindMyCustomValidator(WebDataBinder binder) {
    if ("entityList".equals(binder.getObjectName())) {
        binder.addValidators(new MyCustomValidator());
    }
}
```

If you try to filter the bound argument by setting the value of the annotation, then it won't work for a `@RequestBody` argument. So here I check the object name instead. My method parameter is actually called `entities`, but Spring had decided to call it `entityList`. I had to debug it to discover this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try my solution:

```java
@InitBinder
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    if (CustomerQuickRegisterEntity.class.equals(binder.getTarget().getClass())) {
        binder.addValidators(new YourValidator());
    }
}
```