# How to check multiple Spring DTO validation by sequence?

Tags: spring-boot, validation, annotations, spring-validator

I have request DTO using spring validation as follows.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class DeviceData implements Serializable {
    @NotBlank(message = "device id required")
    private String deviceId;

    @NotBlank(message = "client trans id required")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$"
        , message = "client trans id format error")
    private String clientTransId;

    @NotBlank(message = "device info required")
    private String deviceInfo;

}
```

I want `@NotBlank` to be check first and when it false, not to be check `@Pattern`. and when it true check `@Pattern`.
How it do that?    Please help for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `Group`, like code shows below:

Firstly, you need declare a new Group:

```
public interface Group1 {

}
```

Secondly, declare a custom sequence as you want:

```
// Default is nessary here
@GroupSequence({Default.class, Group1.class})
public interface Sequence {

}
```

Then, add groups on your DTO field:

```
@NotBlank(message = "client trans id required", groups = {Default.class})
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$", message = "client trans id format error", groups = {Group1.class})
private String clientTransId;
```

Finally, using validator and your `Sequence` interface to validate:

```
DeviceData test = new DeviceData();
test.clientTransId = "";

Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<DeviceData>> set = validator.validate(test, Sequence.class);
```

Comment: I don't need Validator. I passed these request by my controller class. Is there any other way call your  Sequence  in my controller.

Comment: Try using `@InitBinder` annotation to bind a new validator in your controller.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120058/initbinder-in-spring-boot-not-working-with-requestbody   this link may helpful.